# Keep text in UITextField between views

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have two `ViewControllers`, X and Y, which both contain `UITextFields`. Starting in X, I enter some text in a field, then switch to Y and enter some text in a field. Going back to X, the text I input is still there, while going again to Y shows the text has disappeared. How can I persist the text in `TextFields` between all views when switching between them?

Comment: are you using a navigationcontroller? or how do you switch from X to Y?

Comment: @AndreSlotta yes I'm using a NavigationController

Comment: and how do you get from X to Y? did you set up a segue in storyboard? or do you do that programmatically?

Comment: @AndreSlotta I click on a button and it segues to Y. Swipe back or hit the navbar Back button to go back to X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possibility: remove your segues in storyboard and implement something like this...

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
  lazy var secondVC: SecondViewController = {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! SecondViewController
    return vc
  }()

  @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because when you go from X to Y, Y instance is created and (I guess) pushed to stack od UINavigationController. When you press back button, Y instance gets deallocated and X is presented again. X instance is the same X instance as this firstly created. When you go again to Y, it's created again, from scratch, as a new instance.

Possible solutions:

- keep the field's values in "root" view controller as custom object, or Dictionary and pass it around presented vcs i.e in `prepareForSegue`. By root I mean the controller that presents the first page of form or just the first page vc - depends on your needs
- store them in user defaults an access in each vc
- keep them in some singleton object that you can access from each controller

Comment: Of course, makes sense. Now I'll have to find a way to keep the original instance of Y

Comment: do you only need X and Y? or are there even more controllers to push?

Comment: @mjr - don't keep whole Y view controller - you just need textField's text which is simple string

Comment: @Kubba: why wouldn't you keep the vc? if there aren't like many many more vcs to push it is ok i think. and instantiating the vc again and again costs performance.

Comment: because you don't need it - textField's text i what you need.